# What are the best ways to increase fertility?

Tags: nutrition, medications, exercise, oral-health, fertility

We are newly married couple. 
What Food habits we need to take care of and what are the best workout tips for us?  If we need to do physical activity - which one is more effective YOGA or Gym Workouts ? and what are the additional precautions I need to take?

Comment: Hi! I am somehow confused by your edit of the question as it looks like you have edited your question after M.Arrowsmith did already provide a thorough explanation and answer to your question. What additional precisions do you need? This would maybe help either M.Arrowsmith or other persons to give you an answer according to your expectations? Although I don't see how M.Arrowsmith's answer can be improved to be honest... Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*I will try to answer your question by using another perspective (risk factors for infertility).*

**MALE**

Among the **main causes of male infertility**, "idiopathic" causes (ie not du to endocrine problems, genetic defects or sperm transport problems) represent 40%.

In the last decades, increasing attention has been given to **environmental factors**. Here a brief overview:

- The **pesticide dibromochloropropane is a well-known cause, as are
  lead, cadmium, and mercury**.
- The possibility that chemicals with estrogenic or antiandrogenic
  activity (“endocrine disruptors”), including insecticides and
  fungicides, may lower sperm counts has attracted much attention
  lately, although direct proof of an effect in men is lacking.
- Occupational and environmental exposure has been associated with
  lower quality semen analyses; **limited data suggest that consumption
  of fruits and vegetables with high pesticide residues may also be
  associated with lower semen quality**.
- Because of the rapid increase in cell phone use around the world,
  studies have been done to investigate whether cell phone usage has
  any detrimental effects on sperm parameters. This issue is
  controversial and definitive data are not yet available.
- **Smoking** – Data on cigarette smoking and its possible effect on sperm
  counts are inconsistent. However, in a meta-analysis of 20
  observational studies, men who smoked cigarettes were more likely to
  have low sperm counts.
- **Hyperthermia** – Hyperthermia has long been thought to impair
  spermatogenesis. Prolonged high testicular temperature may explain
  the infertility associated with spinal cord injuries, varicocele, and
  chronic sauna and Jacuzzi exposure. **Similarly, febrile illness,
  prolonged sitting during work or truck driving, welding, baking,
  tight fitting underwear, and laptop use with increased heat to the
  testes have been proposed to adversely affect male fertility. The
  data to support these associations are inconsistent and may be a very
  weak risk factor for infertility**.

**FEMALE**

**Similarly to male infertility, idiophatic female infertility has been associated with similar risks factors, although some of them show conflicting results and have still to be confirmed.** Here additional information regarding some risk factors:

- **Smoking:** Most series report that **fecundability is decreased if the female partner smokes more than 10 cigarettes per day.** In a 1998 meta-analysis including data from almost 11,000 smoking women and over 19,000 nonsmokers, cigarette smoking by the female partner was associated with a statistically significant increase in infertility compared to nonsmokers (OR 1.60, 95% CI 1.34-1.91)
- **Weight:** most studies report a BMI greater than 27 kg/m2 or a BMI less than 17 kg/m2 is associated with increased ovulatory dysfunction and resultant infertility

Regarding your two specific questions about diet and exercise:

**DIET**

> In healthy couples, there is no strong evidence that dietary
>   variations such as vegetarian diets, low-fat diets, and vitamin or
>   antioxidant-enriched diets improve fertility.

**EXERCISE**

> The intensity and duration of exercise can affect female fertility,
>   but the specific type of exercise does not appear to be a factor. In
>   some epidemiological studies, vigorous/intense physical activity was
>   associated with ovulatory infertility, while others have not
>   observed a significant association

**So avoiding some of those proven risk factors, may reduce your risk of developing infertility. I haven't found any evidenced based data of fertility "stimulants".**

Sources: Swerdloff et al. Causes of male infertility. Uptodate.com. Jul 2016, Hornstein et al. Optimizing natural fertility in healthy couples. Uptodate.com. Jul 2016

Comment: The OP is a female.

Comment: Interesting. Where do you take that information from? Anyway, as the question is not clear, adding information for both gender is certainly useful for future persons having the same concern. Best regards. M. Arrowsmith

Comment: @M.Arrowsmith : Probably from the name.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know taking zinc pills increase the volume of your sperm. Also avoiding hot baths/creating a fresh environment for your scrotum increases the sperm count.

Maybe some exercises to increase testosterone helps too. For best advice man you gotta see a health care professional.